# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS IIS rules www HTTPS and old urls

Tags: redirect, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have 3 rulles in IIS www, https and old url redirects. But it seems to get stuck in a loop and i get an error, is there a way to combine these three so prevent this from occurring?

```
<rule name="SSL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"   redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="www" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.com$"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.test.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
<rule name="OLD URL redirects">
    <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{OldRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

Thought combining them solve the issue? But i couldn't get it to work

Comment: Could you please post the details information about your requirement for the url rewrite rule. Besides. I need to know which domain you have used that face the multiple redirect error.

Answer (score 0):

It turn out that the rules are correct the error was in the RewriteMaps